# Avoid Cucumber Duplicated Steps

Tags: automation, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

How to avoid duplicated Cucumber steps while multiple team members working on different feature files in parallel? 
Sometimes we find some similar steps with different context but are 90%-100% the same. The problem occurs when the tests are complex and need to write new steps for new feature that we didn't have before.

Any tips good tips that could help solving this issue? 
Are there good tools that can manage and search steps to avoid duplicated statements?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Everyone writes scenarios in a different way.

One way you could start to avoid duplication is to document your steps and what they do, so that you and your team can look back on them to see if there is an existing step that they can use.

For steps where the functionality is almost the same, you could merge the step definitions: `Given I have logged in` vs `When I log in` - Cucumber Expression: `"I( have) log(ged) in"`, Regex: `/I(?:| have) log(?:|ged) in/` as an example.

For your example, we would need to know what you're trying to achieve in your step definition. For instance, you could be filling out a form where you have to select an option in a drop down dependant on the user that is logged in:

Psuedo-Code:

```
// Some stuff here to get to the dropdown
if(user.name === "Bob Ross"){
   form.dropdown.select.option(2);
} else if (user.name === "Ellen Ripley"){
   form.dropdown.select.option(3);
} else {
   form.dropdown.select.option(1);
}
// Some other stuff here to complete this step
```

Basically, it depends on what you're attempting to do with your semi-duplicate steps.

Can you check what journey you are completing (with a previously ran step and a variable, a Url, a user that is logged in etc) and do something differently? Perhaps write a helper function for it and keep the step definition as just a block of ifs to choose the right one.

Can you merge steps that hold the same functionality?

If you can do either of these, then you should be good to go.